# C - changing values of a structure passed by reference to a function

Tags: c, structure

The code below returns an "error: request for member 'height' in something not a structure or union". I would like to see `bob`'s height change from 4 to 5 after `doStuff` is called. Can anyone tell me why this doesn't work? Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct person{
    int height;
    int weight;
};

void doStuff(struct person *chris);

int main(){

    struct person bob = {4,4};
    doStuff(&bob);
    printf("%d", bob.height);

    return 0;
}

void doStuff(struct person *steve){

    steve.height = 5;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`steve` is a pointer to the structure, so instead of

```
steve.height = 5;
```

try

```
steve->height = 5;
```

or a bit more more cumbersome

```
(*steve).height = 5;
```

Comment: That worked, but it's brand new to me, can I get the name of that operator so I can do a little reading? Thanks!

Comment: It is "structure dereference".

Answer (score 2):

There is a syntax error in structure pointer usage

You have to use like this inside `doStuff`. Because steve is pointer variable here.

```
 steve->height = 5;
```

`->` is Structure dereference  operator

`.`  is Structure reference  operator